# Programmatically set active facets on non search page

Tags: 7, views, search

I'm using facet api with search api and SOLR. This all works as expected.

For non-search pages I use the views facet block and this displays the facets as required.

What I want to do though is have some of the facets pre-selected on non search pages.

For example:
I have a views page: example.com/london I would like to show facets with 'london' preselected as if I was on a search page for london.

I've tried using a contextual filter on the views facet block and it half works. It shows only the selected city BUT the facet checkbox isn't checked; and if I click any of the other facets it does not show results filtered by city...

Any suggestions how I can get this to work?

Comment: OK. I can get the behaviour I want by hacking facetapi/plugins/facetapi/adapter.inc and substituting my own parameters into setParams().

I really don't want to go down this route but can't seem to find a way to access the adapter object early enough. I did manage to set the parameters without hacking but it seemed to fire after the facets were built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, despite the overwhelming response ;) after about 20 hours of banging my head against the desk I have this figured. I'm not sure if it is the most efficient way to do this, but I don't think the overheads are massive.

I did end up hooking into the adapter class but I couldn't find a facetapi hook that was called at the right time. In the end, I used `hook_init`.

You will need to get your parameters `($SOME_ID_VARIABLE)` into the code. I used the current URL via `request_path()` and got node IDs from this.

The important bits of the code looks something like:

```
function MY_MODULE_init(){
  $searcher = 'search_api@MY_INDEX';
  $adapter = facetapi_adapter_load($searcher);
  $param_arr = array();

  $param_arr['f'][] = 'field_WHATEVER_FIELD:'.$SOME_ID_VARIABLE;
  $param_arr['q'] = 'VIEWS_SEARCH_PAGE/search';
  $adapter->setParams($param_arr);
}
```

Oh, and you still need to use a views facet block to get the facets to show up on the non-search page. I have used some caching on this block and everything still seems to work as expected.

The info on this [page](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi/issues/1715202) got me going in the right direction.